# Link Keychain Internet Password To Mail.app Account

Tags: c++, macos, email, applescript, keychain

I'm having some problems linking a keychain internet password with a Mail.app e-mail account created using Applescript. I don't want to use the "set password to" Applescript command as I want my application to maintain access to the keychain entry I create.

So here is basically what I am doing:

1) Create the keychain entry as follows:

```
SecTrustedApplicationRef objApp[2];
CFArrayRef arrApps;
SecAccessRef objAccess;
SecKeychainItemRef objKeychainItem;
SecProtocolType nProtocolType;

::SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath (NULL,&objApp[0]);
::SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath ("/Applications/Mail.App",
                                       &objApp[1]);

arrApps = ::CFArrayCreate (kCFAllocatorDefault,(const void **) &objApp,
                           2,NULL);
::SecAccessCreate (CFSTR ("mail.myserver.com",arrApps,&objAccess);

nPort = 0;
nProtocolType = kSecProtocolTypePOP3;

SecKeychainAttribute objAttrList[] = {
     { kSecLabelItemAttr,    17, (char *) "mail.myserver.com" },
     { kSecAccountItemAttr,  20, (char *) "someone@myserver.com" },
     { kSecServerItemAttr,   17, (char *) "mail.myserver.com" },
     { kSecPortItemAttr,     sizeof (int), &nPort },
     { kSecProtocolItemAttr, sizeof (SecProtocolType), &nProtocolType }
};

SecKeychainAttributeList objAttributes =
                         { sizeof (objAttrList) / sizeof (objAttrList[0]),
                           objAttrList
                         };

::SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent (kSecInternetPasswordItemClass,
                                    &objAttributes,
                                    12, "somepassword"
                                    NULL,
                                    objAccess,&objKeychainItem);
```

2) Create an account using Applescript:

```
tell application "Mail"
     set newacct to make new pop account with properties
         { name:"someone@myserver.com",
           user name:"someone@myserver.com",    
           uses ssl:true,
           server name:"mail.myserver.com",
           authentication: password,
           port:995,
           full name:"Someone",
           email addresses:{"someone@myserver.com"}
         }
end tell
```

Both parts work individually, yet Mail does not associate the keychain entry with the created account. I must be missing a step, but I just cannot see it, so any help would be appreciated.